# Can I specify a transaction name in TransactionScope

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactionscope

I know I can specify the transaction name by

```
SqlConnection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");
```

But it seems there is no way in the case of TransactionScope. Could somebody give some hints?

Answer (score 2):

There is none.

The reason being that the classes in the [`System.Transaction` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.aspx) can apply to *any* transactional resource, not just SQL Server.

That said, if you had a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) that managed a transaction with SQL Server as well as say, a [transactional file system such as NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS), the name wouldn't have any meaning to NTFS.

If you want to use a name, and you are *only* using SQL Server, then you need to manage the transaction from the [`SqlConnection` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) (as you've shown with the call to the [`BeginTransaction` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1562zz1.aspx)), otherwise, there's no way to do it with `TransactionScope` (although I did think there would be some sort of information, even in the form of an extension on the [`TransactionInformation` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioninformation.aspx)).